# unable to close a div using selectors

Tags: jquery, css

I didn't know how to write the question down in the title without writing an article.
Basically i want to click on the plus sign and it opens a div then within that div their is an exit button in the top right corner. When you click the exit button i want it to close the opened div. unfortunately i am unable to single out that selector to close out the div.

I have everything working except the exit button. 
here is [my jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w66QF/)

Here is the jquery

```
function showSign(){
    var plus = $('.plusSign');
    health = $('.plus'),
    health.hide();
    plus.on('click', function(){
    var val1 = $(this).children('div').attr('class'),
    val2 = val1.split(' ')[0];
    $('.'+val2).show();
    // alert(val2);
});
var closeBtn = $('.exitBtn');
    closeBtn.on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent('div.plus').hide();//this is where i am having problems
    });
}showSign();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that an error ? health = $('.plus'),
    health.hide();

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns - That's an error that doesn't actually stop the code working. `health` will be created as a global variable since it's not declared with `var`, but the element will still be hidden.

Comment: I hope you got answer for your question. From my point of view, this is complex design. You can simplify it and use id for elements it will improve performance.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns: thanks i didn't see that. I will fix:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following for your X button click handler:

```
    closeBtn.on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('div.plus').hide();
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w66QF/9/

Where you had `$(this).parent('div.plus')` it was not selecting any elements to hide because `.parent()` doesn't search up through the DOM tree, it selects the immediate parent if it matches the provided selector, or nothing (if the immediate parent doesn't match the selector). The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) that I suggest instead searches up until it finds a match (or reaches the highest level).

You also need to add [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), otherwise the click event from the X bubbles up to your other click handler because the X is contained inside the `.plusSign` element so then that shows the popup again immediately after hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) like,

```
var closeBtn = $('.exitBtn');
$('#diagnostic').on('click', '.exitBtn', function () {
    $(this).closest('div.plus').hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rVu4K/)

Answer (score 0):

`.plusSign` is entire div. `.exitBtn` is children of it. On clicking `.exitBtn`, click event of `.plusSign` is also being triggered.

Assign click event for `.plusSign span` instead.

Write:

```
var plus = $('.plusSign span');
var closeBtn = $('.exitBtn');
health = $('.plus'),
health.hide();
plus.on('click', function () {    
    var val1 = $(this).parent().children('div').attr('class'),
        val2 = val1.split(' ')[0];
    $('.' + val2).show();
});
closeBtn.on('click', function () {    
    $(this).closest('.plus').hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/w66QF/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code in your script

```
<script>
        function showSign(){
    var plus = $('.plusSign');
            health = $('.plus'),
            health.hide();

    plus.on('click', function(){
        var val1 = $(this).children('div').attr('class'),
                val2 = val1.split(' ')[0];
                $('.'+val2).show();
        // alert(val2);
    });
    $('.exitBtn').click(function(){
         $(this).closest("div.plusSign").hide('slow');

        });
    }showSign();


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var accordion, hidden, handle_event;

accordion = $("#diagnostic");

// hide all div.plus elements
hidden = accordion.find('.plus').hide();

handle_event = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var element;

    element = $(event.target);

    hidden.hide();

    // show nested accordion item (if it's not closing click)
    element.find('.plus').show();
};

// handle events
accordion.on('click', '.plusSign', handle_event);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine. Make just 2 minor changes:

- Pass `event` parameter in the function on click and then use `event.stopPropagation()`.
- instead of `parent('div.plus')`, use `parents('div.plus')`

Something like this:

```
closeBtn.on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parents('div.plus').hide();
});
```

here is your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/w66QF/16/

Good luck!